# Is it possible to create a choropleth map of a single US State in plotly?

Tags: plotly, plotly-dash

Is it possible to create a map of a single state or multiple states that are next to each other? i.e. Create a map of California, Nevada and Arizona only and not show the rest of the United States?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can just filter out the geojson features that you do not need, i.e. in your case all states but California, Nevada and Arizona. Here is a small Dash app demonstrating the concept using Dash Leaflet,

```
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
import json
import dash_leaflet as dl
from dash_leaflet import express as dlx

# Input data.
with open("assets/us-states.json", 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
marks = [0, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200, 500, 1000]
colorscale = ['#FFEDA0', '#FED976', '#FEB24C', '#FD8D3C', '#FC4E2A', '#E31A1C', '#BD0026', '#800026']


def get_style(feature):
    color = [colorscale[i] for i, item in enumerate(marks) if feature["properties"]["density"] > item][-1]
    return dict(fillColor=color, weight=2, opacity=1, color='white', dashArray='3', fillOpacity=0.7)


# Create colorbar.
ctg = ["{}+".format(mark, marks[i + 1]) for i, mark in enumerate(marks[:-1])] + ["{}+".format(marks[-1])]
colorbar = dlx.categorical_colorbar(categories=ctg, colorscale=colorscale, width=300, height=30, position="bottomleft")
# Create geojson.
options = dict(hoverStyle=dict(weight=5, color='#666', dashArray=''), zoomToBoundsOnClick=True)
geojson = dlx.geojson(data, id="geojson", defaultOptions=options, style=get_style)
# Filter out the desired states.
target_states = ["California", "Nevada", "Arizona"]
geojson.data["features"] = [f for f in geojson.data["features"] if f["properties"]["name"] in target_states]
# Create app.
app = dash.Dash()
app.layout = html.Div([dl.Map(children=[dl.TileLayer(), geojson, colorbar], center=[39, -98], zoom=4)],
                      style={'width': '100%', 'height': '50vh', 'margin': "auto", "display": "block"}, id="map")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server()
```

To run the example, you must put the `us-states.json` file in your assets folder. You can get it from the [original Leaflet example](https://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/) or from [here](https://dash-leaflet.herokuapp.com/assets/us-states.json).

Comment: By the way, when i run it with app = dash.Dash(prevent_initial_callbacks=True) I get the error message Dash() got an unexpected keyword argument 'prevent_initial_callbacks'

Comment: Is there a way to only show those states without showing the rest of the United Sates? When I run your example, I still see a map of the entire United States, but California, Nevada and Arizona are highlighted. I'd also like to have only these 3 states show and take up "the entire map area" (make them bigger).

Comment: In the event that there aren't any maps of individual states, showing me how to filter the states for the geojson file is still a major help for an alternative way of completing this project, so thank you for that ;)

Comment: The 'prevent_initial_callbacks' callbacks flags was introduced in Dash 1.12.0, so you probably have a version older than that. As it is not essential to this particular example, I have removed in from the code above.

Comment: If you don't need the "map" itself, but only the colored polygons representing the states, you can just remove the 'dl.TileLayer()' object from the children of the map; then the background will be gray.